# Is the solution to this exercise wrong?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, inference

Here's the exercise:
[image]

and here's the solution:
[image]

is this not a mistake?? The exercise says that the two groups are normally distributed. It doesn't say anything about them having the same variance. All the working out done in the question is the typical one that we use when we have two normal samples with different means and same variance and we want to check whether they have the same mean. But this is clearly not that situation.

Can we still use the same procedure? And if it is correct, why is it?

Comment: I would think that we had to proceed as follows:
We have $Y_{1i} \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$  and $Y_{2i} \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ hence $\hat{\mu_1}=\bar{Y_1}=\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_{I=1}^{n_1}(Y_{1i}-\bar{Y_1})^2$ and similarly $\hat{\mu_2}=\bar{Y_2}=\frac{1}{n_2}\sum_{I=1}^{n_2}(Y_{2i}-\bar{Y_2})^2$ so that $$\hat{\mu_1}-\hat{\mu_2} \sim N(\mu_1-\mu_2,\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2})$$ and then use the CLT ? For example then $Z = \frac{\hat{\mu_1}-\hat{\mu_2}-(\mu_1-\mu_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}}} \sim N(0,1)$

Comment: and then we just need to find an estimate for the denominator. For example starting from $$\frac{(n_1-1)\hat{\sigma_1}^2}{\sigma_1^2} \sim \chi_{n_1-1}^2$$ and similarly $$\frac{(n_2-1)\hat{\sigma_2}^2}{\sigma_2^2} \sim \chi_{n_2-1}^2$$.and somehow join them?

Comment: For example then we could rewrite the denominator as $$\sqrt{\frac{n_2\sigma_1^2+n_1\sigma_2^2}{n_1n_2}}$$ and then we could consider $$\frac{n_2}{n_1-1}\frac{(n_1-1)\hat{\sigma_1}^2}{\sigma_1^2}$$ and notice that $$E[\frac{n_2}{n_1-1}\frac{(n_1-1)\hat{\sigma_1}^2}{\sigma_1^2}] = n_2$$ and $$Var[\frac{n_2}{n_1-1}\frac{(n_1-1)\hat{\sigma_1}^2}{\sigma_1^2}] = \frac{2n_2^2}{n_1-1}$$

Comment: and for example we can notice that $\frac{n_2}{n_1-1}$ is a constant and recall the property that if $Y\sim \gamma(\beta,\alpha)$ then $X = bY \sim \gamma(b\beta,\alpha)$ so that if we have $b = \frac{n_2}{n_1-1}$ then $$\frac{n_2}{n_1-1}\frac{(n_1-1)\hat{\sigma_1}^2}{\sigma_1^2} \sim \gamma(2 \cdot \frac{n_2}{n_1-1}, \frac{n_1-1}{2})$$

Comment: but so actually we have that $$\frac{n_2\hat{\sigma_1}^2}{\sigma_1^2} \sim \gamma(\frac{2n_2}{n_1-1}, \frac{n_1-1}{2})$$ for $$Var[\sigma_1^2 \frac{n_2\hat{\sigma_1}^2}{\sigma_1^2}] = \sigma_1^4(\frac{2n_2}{n_1-1}\cdot \frac{n_1-1}{2}) = \sigma_1^4n_2$$

Comment: and again we can use the same property for gamma functions and finally write $$n_2\hat{\sigma_1}^2 \sim \gamma(\frac{2\sigma_1^2n_2}{n_1-1},\frac{n_1-1}{2})$$ and similarly we would find $$n_1\hat{\sigma_2}^2 \sim \gamma(\frac{2\sigma_2^2n_1}{n_2-1},\frac{n_2-1}{2})$$

Comment: Then we just have to sum them and to divide by $n_1n_2$

Comment: Please explain why you think it would be erroneous to assume equal variances in the two groups.  Do you have any evidence for that?

Comment: @whuber well in general in mathematics we try to be general. They are two different groups, so one would expect them to be different. One should prove (as in the answer they do with the mean) that the variances are equal

Comment: Fortunately, this is not a question of mathematics!  With statistical questions it is frequently useful--if not crucial--to bring in general knowledge and common sense.  Here, it would be impossible to prove the variances are equal, so if you insist on that, you will never get anywhere.  Now it is true that a careful analyst would likely adopt a procedure that does not assume equal variances--but that doesn't mean the procedure shown here is wrong.  The real issue concerns what one might be giving up, in terms of the quality of the decision, by assuming equal variances.

Comment: @whuber how do we know it would be impossible to prove that the variances are equal? Furthermore, I understand your point. Although, as this is just an introductory exercise, I would expect it to specify that the variances are equal.

Comment: It's a trivial observation that you can't *prove* anything using data: all you can do is suggest a hypothesis is implausible.  The corresponding (null) hypothesis would be that the variances are unequal: but no test in the world has any power to demonstrate the implausibility of that.  By the logic of statistical inference, then, it is mathematically impossible to demonstrate equal variances.  Indeed, equality of variances is of little relevance: what matters is whether they are *sufficiently close* to justify the use of this test.